# jquery ajax refreshes page on failed callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

so i'm just not sure where i'm going wrong on this issue.  it's one of those things everything was working fine and i made an adjustment, then i fell asleep and can't remember what i did.  so my issue is that this ajax call fails:

```
var url = 'lib/php/addToCart.php';
    var sent = $.post(url, data, null, 'json');
    sent.done(function (data) {
        $('.badge').html(Object.keys(data).length);
        console.log('item added to cart');
        alert("Added To Your Cart.  Please Continue Shopping");

    });
    sent.fail(function (data, b, c) {

        console.log("failed adding item: " + c);
        var propValue;
        for(var propName in b) {
            propValue = b[propName];

            console.log(propName,propValue);
        }
    });
```

the only errors i can get from the fail is "error" and when i do the jqXHR error i get a function in response.

here is my php file that is being called:

```
session_start();

$itemNum = $_POST['upc'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$qty = 1;
$cartData = $conn->prepare("SELECT available FROM yardSale.dvdTbl WHERE upc = ?");
$cartData->bind_param("s", $itemNum);
$cartData->execute();
$cartData->store_result();
$cartData->bind_result($available);
$cartData->fetch();
$linePrice = $price * $qty;

$cartName = $title;

$_SESSION['cart'][$cartName] = array(
    "cartName"  => $cartName,
    "itemNum"   => $itemNum,
    "title"     => $title,
    "itemPrice" => $price,
    "linePrice" => $linePrice,
    "qty"       => $qty,
    "available" => $available
);


echo json_encode($_SESSION['cart']);
```

and then if  you need it i have an event handler to go to the function with the ajax call:

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var upcNum = $(this).attr('id');
    var formID = 'info:' + upcNum;
    console.log(upcNum);
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(formData);
    addItem(formData);
```

i'm sure this is another one of those really stupid things i'm over looking... but i can't figure out where the error would be coming from, or why the page is refreshing.

in fire bug the file just shows up red and only has the request headers, no response headers.  the real kicker for me is that the php file actually processes the information like it's supposed to and the json that should be returned would be valid json.

and please don't laugh at my code... if you want to help i take criticism very well; but please don't patronize me.

Comment: Even if youre tired you should provide only relevant and complete code.
Are you clicking a link that triggers the AJAX-call or any other element with an `href`-attribute on it? If so you should add `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete code. I only left or the actual event handler and the function name.  Won't happen again

Comment: and you were absolutely correct Code Spirit.  one of the changes i made before i fell asleep was to turn off the general event.preventDefault() to troubleshoot something completely different.

Comment: What if you use return false instead of event.preventDefault ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed event.preventDefault()... thanks Code Spirit

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in this part of code:

```
for(var propName in b) {
    propValue = b[propName];
    console.log(propName,propValue);
}
```

The variable propName is not the **index** but is the **value**, so you must do something like this:

```
for(var propIndex in Object.keys(b)) {
    propValue = b[propIndex];
    console.log(propIndex,propValue);
}
```

Comment: I'm not certain that's the issue with this problem as the error still happens even when I don't have this code in it.  But I do think you helped me solve another issue I was having!

Comment: I guess `b` is an object so it doesnt has any indices.

Comment: @CodeSpirit In Javascript, objects has indices..
Just look this:
{ 
    foo: 'bar',
    see: true,
    gee: false
    etc.. etc..
}

Comment: Its no index but the porperty name. Its often mixed up with asociative arrays, linked lists or similiar but actially its a property (member of an object).

Comment: @CodeSpirit Yes, I mean a key, I'm sorry but I confused key with index! :)